# Unable to use '*' to search/replace -- sed

Tags: sed

I want to make all a.b.c.top*.gz mentions to new-word/new-table.

Something like -->

*es.fr.en.top20.gz* becomes *binarised-model/phrase-table*

I did this :

```
sed -i 's/es\.fr\.en\.top*\.gz/binarised-model\/phrase-table/g' top*/mert-work/moses.ini
```

I had initially not used backslash before periods, but, once it did not work, I thought maybe period is tricky.

But, it does not seem to replace anything. What's going wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `*` as a wildcard is correct for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) globbing, but not if you work with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), which is the case when using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). Instead of `*`, try `.*`.

In [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), `*` means match the preceding character any number of times. The wildcard character is `.`, so `.*` matches any number of any characters.

If you know that the character you want to match is always a number, it's safer to use `[0-9]*`. If you even know how many characters this number will have, then you can even use e.g. `[0-9]\{2\}` to match exactly two numerals.

Answer (score 3):

Sed uses regular expressions, not shell globbing. That means that (1) `.` matches any single character except a newline, so you are right to escape them to match a literal dot, and (2) `*` matches zero or more of the token preceding it, here that's `p`.  You need

```
sed -i 's/es\.fr\.en\.top.*\.gz/binarised-model\/phrase-table/g' top*/mert-work/moses.ini
#                        ˆ
```

Comment: Crap, you guys are so awesome. I had to accept one and I realized you have way more reputation. Adding some water to sea does not make a difference. Thanks you both ! Will remember.